# Controller and Action name autocomplete in HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

I'm have custom HtmlHelper for creating navigation menu links. Now I want to add intellisense support to this helper.

```
public static class MenuLinkHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

For example, when typing:

```
@Html.MenuLink("Mainpage", "Index", "")
```

I want to see autocompletion of controller's and action's name.
How I may to do this?

P.S.: I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: Resharper does this. Look into purchasing Resharper.

Answer (score 0):

You will need plugin to Visual Studio. The autocomplete is always done as a plugin.

Comment: Garath, is autocomplete for standard html helpers implemented done as a plugin? I'm thought, it implemented by attributes or special comments in classes.

Comment: I will have to check it in original asp.net mvc source, but i am almost sure that it is done without attributes

Answer (score 0):

I think this support is burned-in into the Resharper for the factory helper extension.